# Do reducer functions for React's useReducer hook have to be pure?

Tags: reactjs

[The docs for the `useReducer` hook](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usereducer) are somewhat vague:

> Accepts a reducer of type `(state, action) => newState`, and returns the current state paired with a `dispatch` method. (If you’re familiar with Redux, you already know how this works.)

[The Redux docs](https://redux.js.org/basics/reducers#handling-actions) then say

> It's very important that the reducer stays pure. Things you should **never** do inside a reducer:
>
> - Mutate its arguments;
> - Perform side effects like API calls and routing transitions;
> - Call non-pure functions, e.g. `Date.now()` or `Math.random()`.

But I'm not using Redux. The React docs don't seem to say anywhere that the reducer has to be pure. There's just that vague statement that people who know Redux "already know how this works".

So, **do reducer functions for `useReducer` need to be pure?** If so, why exactly? If not, *should* they be pure? Again if so, why?

I'm imagining an action updating state to "loading", and at the same time firing off an API call, which on response would dispatch a different action and so update the state again.